# I require to change the cell formulas to values only when a certain date passes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a pivot table on excel that automatically updates with values every day.

I have columns next to the pivot table for EACH DAY that grabs data from the updated pivot table using a simple formula, for example I11-V11.

However, when the date for today passes, i want the cell in the specific column for that date to change to a value i.e be fixed.

Is there a way that this could be done?

[image: image showing snippet of spreadsheet]

Comment: We can't see from your screenshot which cells are I11:V11. What is the formula that you want to convert to a value? Or is the formula `=I11-V11` Maybe you can write a formula that only uses data for a specific time frame.

Comment: Hi the formula i want to convert to value is I11-V11 where I11 is for example "Completed 29.01.19" and V11 is the "COMPLETED" section in the pivot table.

Comment: However i want the formula to change to value ONLY when the date on top passes

Comment: does the pivot source data have dates?

Comment: No it does not have dates

Comment: There are 3 parts to your solution. 1) What do you want to show on (?) or before the date passes? You already have that formula but you don't tell us. 2) What do you want to show on (?) or after the date passes. You know but you don't tell us. 3) Where is the date? It seems to be in a cell whose address we don't know, perhaps hidden in text. I guess it's in the 2nd pink captioned column & onward but it would be nice if you wouldn't let us guess and tell us the address of the 2nd pink cell. Also is the range I11:V11 in your screen shot?

Comment: The formula you need is a very simple IF statement. But before it can be constructed some preparation is necessary. For one, set a cell format in the ink captions, like, `"Completed" dd/mm/yyyy` and then make sure the value entered is a real date, not some text. After that, edit your question to provide all the necessary information and, voila, the solution is within grasp.

Comment: Take a look at the `Worksheet_Change` event maybe.

Comment: Simply put, the dates are stated within the red highlighted cells. All i need is to somehow change those red columns from a formula which is a simple subtraction to a fixed value AFTER the date has passed.

Answer (score 1):

You want a snapshot of the data. Manually, you could copy and paste the data over itself with Paste Special > Values.

You can create a VBA macro for that, but the trigger for the macro would still have to be manual. Because if it is dynamic, once the header date is in the past, any formula will have already updated dynamically and yesterday's values will be gone.

So, either manually copy/paste values (or fire up the macro to do that), or add a date column to the data source, so a formula can associate a value with the correct date.